# What is a word for "to make explicit"?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

The definition of explicit that I wish to use:

> stated clearly and in detail, leaving no room for confusion or doubt.
>
> **E.g.** *the speaker's intentions were not made explicit.*

My motivation: I'm analyzing 'Follower' (by Seamus Heaney) right now and I want to comment on the word "exactly" in 'Mapping the furrow exactly'. My comment is something along the lines of

> "Mapping the furrow" already attributes a high level of skill and precision to his father. The use of the word 'exactly' adds an extra layer to the phrase and **makes it explicit**.

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/make%20explicit

Comment: @Solocutor "explicate" is not what I'm looking for, as it means to analyze or break down.

Comment: The link I just posted should give you a list of synonyms of "make explicit" not just explicate.

Comment: @Solocutor What I mean is the definition for which the synonyms are given is "explicate". (it says "as in explicate")

Comment: So none of those words were appropriate?

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/explicitation) gives the noun _explicitation_, with suitable caveats: explicitation ‎(plural explicitations)

(rare, possibly nonstandard) The process or fact of becoming explicit or of causing to be explicit; that which makes something explicit.  ...
Usage is confined almost entirely to academic journals, and to the field of translation studies. I can only find 'explicitate' in a non-mainstream dictionary; perhaps OED lists it. But there will doubtless be similar caveats.

Comment: Suggestions: and further intensifies it. Or: gives it greater intensity. Personally, I find that the idea of explicit here is not correct for the meaning of what happens to the phrase when the word exactly is added to it....

Comment: If I were going to **specify** a word, it would be "explicitify".

Comment: What about "explicate"?

Comment: It should be "to explicitate"... but the verb does not seem to exist. :-(

Answer (score 7):

I think you are looking for ***[to specify](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/specify):***

> - state  a fact or requirement clearly and precisely:
>     *the agency failed to specify that the workers were not their employees.*

(ODO)

Comment: Close, but it doesn't capture exactly what I'm looking for. Please see my edit for additional context.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the word you were looking might be "clarify".

[Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=clarify+definition)

And with regard to generally removing doubt or confusion, "disambiguation" should be considered.

[Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=disambiguation+definition)

I'll just leave this here, maybe it's what you were looking for, maybe not.

Answer (score 2):

"Mapping the furrow" already attributes a high level of skill and precision to his father. The use of the word 'exactly' adds an extra layer to the phrase and makes it explicit.
reworking:

"Mapping the furrow" attributes on its own a high level of skill and precision to his father. The addition of 'exactly' intensifies the visual impact of the phrase and suggests an obsessive or over zealous aspect to the activity.

Comment: I agree with this tack. The OP's underlying question is really what's the right word/phrase for explaining "exactly" in the poem, which does not seem to be "makes it explicit".

Comment: I disagree with this tack. The explanation should be more accessible and commonly understood than what is being explained, but this rework seems focused instead on making the language more academic and specific.